# How to call AsyncCallback with a parameter in an BeginGetRequestStream (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asynccallback, get-request

```
    public void SendPost(string code)
    {
        // Create the web request object
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Resource.Url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        //Start the request
        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);
    }
```

I want to call the GetRequestStreamCallback with an parameter.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why are you using `BeginGetRequestStream` instead of [GetRequestStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststreamasync(v=vs.110).aspx) ? It's available in all supported .NET versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda instead of a method group.

That is:

```
webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(result => GetRequestStreamCallback(result, someParameter)), webRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of BeginGetRequestStream, use [GetRequestStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststreamasync(v=vs.110).aspx). With it, you can use the `async/await` keywords to await for an operation to complete asynchronously and continue execution :

```
public async Task SendPost(string code)
{
    // Create the web request object
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Resource.Url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    //Start the request
    var stream=await webRequest.GetRequestStream(webRequest);
    MyStreamProcessingMethod(stream);
    ...
}
```

`GetRequestStreamAsync` and `async/await` are available in all supported .NET versions.